# UWP app crashes when rotate or zoom map with pinch

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, bing-maps, xamarin.uwp, uwp-maps

I am working on Xamarin. Forms UWP Map and whenever I try to zoom map with pinch instantly it crashes with no information.
Below is the link of sample project I have referred, and I am adding my sample XAML code as well. Please help me out as this has blocked me, any suggestion will be greatly appreciated

xaml:

```
   <ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
      xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
         x:Class="TEST.Pages.MapPage">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <maps:Map x:Name="LocationMap" 
        IsShowingUser="False" 
        MapType="Street" />
</ContentPage.Content>
```

sample project link:

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WorkingWithMaps

Comment: Whatever you want folks to look at from that external link should be moved to the body of the question. If it is code relevant to the question please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Updating xamarin forms will resolve this issue